# call React class with a variable string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This example uses Reactjs and [Datamaps](http://datamaps.github.io/).

I am making a tool that is supposed to select states from a map. A portion of that code is below.

```
datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit.MI').on('click', function(){
  var state = 'mi';
  if (sting.state.mi === 'und'){
    sting.setState({trumpnums: sting.state.trumpnums + sting.state.miv, mi: 'right'});  
    map.updateChoropleth({MI:'red'});
    datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit.MI').on('mouseout', function(){
      map.updateChoropleth({MI:'red'}); 
    }); 
  }
});
```

To save me from having to repeat a lot of this for each state, I was hoping to store my React classname in a variable.

All instances of `MI` and `mi` refer to Michigan. So, I was hoping that instead of having to type`sting.state.mi`, I was hoping for something like

```
var state = 'mi';
if (sting.state.{state} === 'und'){
  //rest of my code
}
```

I already set a placeholder for `var state` as you can see in the code above. However, it does not work with my React class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript bracket notation:

```
if (sting.state[state] === 'und')
```